# C Programming: Drawing shapes on screen (windows compatible)

Tags: c

So I have been doing a lot of googling and couldnt find anything of value. I come from web development and I often had fun with the HTML5 canvas api. When I search for information regarding drawing contexts in the basic C programming language, I could only find APIs associated with Apple such as Quartz. Every article is about this so called cocoa or IOs / MAC. Honestly, nothing for microsoft.

How do I draw a basic shape on screen with the C Language?

Comment: Google GDI for starter..

Comment: Well, you would *want* to use a graphics library. With that your program will have to be a Win32. You cannot do much with the console window.

Comment: You won't find drawing contexts in the basic C programming language. C is a low level language.

Comment: @EvanCarslake so basically only 32 bit? So its useless for real apps then? Id have to use Java, C++ etc?

Comment: @WeatherVane so only apples provides apis for that? Is C not used for creating apps with interfaces?

Comment: @Asperger I don't know a lot on that subject, but I am very sure 32 bit programs work fine on 64 bit (windows.) In-fact I am pretty sure most of the programs on your computer is 32 bit based. That you do not need to worry about at all. It will work. Java the same, if the user has java installed on their computer and web browser, it will work. So, you can use C or C++ with GDI, or Java with one of its graphic libraries available.

Comment: He means the Windows API (commonly referred to as Win32). You can do it in C - that's how I learned.

Comment: @Asperger graphics are not a standard feature of the C language, but APIs and GUIs are accessible from the C language. Windows has such, but you didn't find it. Otherwise, how could developers make Windows apps?

Comment: @WeatherVane I see, so like Johnny Mopp said I should use the Windows API. Is this something worth reading? http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/

Comment: @Asperger here winter is approaching... resurface next spring, soonest ;) ... perhaps take on board OpenGL and/or DirectX too. They are graphics rendering systems with Windows implementation.

Comment: @WeatherVane OpenGL is cool. Already have some experience with the WebGL version. I dont know if OpenGL is somewhat overkill for 2D though. Im a starter with very low level languages like C so sorry if I say rubbish : (

Comment: For 2D, take a look at Cairo which works on Windows, Mac and Linux at http://cairographics.org/ and then look also at Allegro http://liballeg.org/

Comment: Look also into cross-platform libraries like [Qt](http://qt.io) & [libsdl](http://libsdl.org/)

Comment: You can use [`Polygon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162814(v=vs.85).aspx) to draw both simple and more complicated shapes. However, this being Windows, you need a solid piece of code for the supporting scaffold. You cannot just go ahead and draw anything, anytime, anywhere - not under Windows.

Comment: @Jongware if I learn the Windows API (Win32) then not dependent on commercial libaries right? I mean no licencing and stuff like that.

Comment: Not if you restrict yourself to the functions that come with Windows. But, there is not a Windows API for *everything possible*, so it ultimately depends on what sort of program you want to write - it still could need external libraries. I cannot tell, based only on what you told so far.